# Getting Shipment Increment ID by Order ID in Magento via SOAP

Tags: php, magento, soap

We have an integration with Magento built entirely around the [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php). For example, a shipment is created like so:

```
$this->_client = @new SoapClient($this->getWsdl(), $context);
        if ($this->_client) {
            $this->_session = $this->_client->login($this->magentoUser, $this->magentoKey);
            return $this;
        }
```

...

```
$result = $this->_client->salesOrderShipmentCreate(
            $this->_session,
            $id
        );
return $result;
```

And tracking is added similarly. The problem is, if I need to **update** tracking for whatever reason, I need the `shipment_increment_id`. From our system, I pull the `order_id`. So I need to query Magento to get the associated `shipment_increment_id` from the `order_id`.

So, [this seems to be exactly the solution I need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734134/how-to-get-shipment-increment-id-by-order-id-in-magento), however, there is no `Mage` object in our codebase, we're communicating entirely via the SoapClient. Looking through the [docs on the sales object](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/salesOrder.html), I'm not really seeing a solution here.

How can I get the shipment ID using the order ID via Magento's SOAP API?

Comment: For people landing here coming from Google search results, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29286210 where it has a full SOAP API approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using default methods of soap you wouldn't be able to get shipment id by order id. For this you need to override Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Shipment/Api.php and extend the method as mentioned below.

In app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/etc/config.xml

```
<models>
    <sales>
        <rewrite>
            <order_shipment_api>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Sales_Order_Shipment_Api</order_shipment_api>
        </rewrite>
    </sales>
</models>
```

Now create a method in app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/Model/Sales/Order/Shipment/Api.php

```
class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Sales_Order_Shipment_Api extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Api
{
    /**
     * Retrieve shipment information
     *
     * @param string $shipmentIncrementId
     * @return array
     */
    public function info($id, $attribute = null)
    {
        if(!empty($attribute)){
            $ids = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter($attribute, $id)
                ->getAllIds();
            if (!empty($ids)) {
                reset($ids);
                $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->load(current($ids));
            }
        }else{
            $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->loadByIncrementId($id);
        }

        /* @var $shipment Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment */
        if (!$shipment->getId()) {
            $this->_fault('not_exists');
        }

        $result = $this->_getAttributes($shipment, 'shipment');

        $result['items'] = array();
        foreach ($shipment->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $result['items'][] = $this->_getAttributes($item, 'shipment_item');
        }

        $result['tracks'] = array();
        foreach ($shipment->getAllTracks() as $track) {
            $result['tracks'][] = $this->_getAttributes($track, 'shipment_track');
        }

        $result['comments'] = array();
        foreach ($shipment->getCommentsCollection() as $comment) {
            $result['comments'][] = $this->_getAttributes($comment, 'shipment_comment');
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Now you can call this Soap method to get shipment info (including shipment id)

```
$result = $this->_client->salesOrderShipmentInfo($sessionId, $orderId, 'order_id');
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: "In app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/etc/config.xml" Could you just expand on this a bit? I'm only familiar working with Magento as far as our codebase goes, which is just built around using the SoapClient. Does this answer assume Magento is installed somewhere?

Comment: Yes, that purely means magento is installed somewhere and either you or your magento admin has to do these customisation in magento module.

In app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/etc/config.xml is the main configuration file of module "Namespace_Modulename" (an arbitrary name), I can give you complete code of this file you need.

Comment: Thank you -- no need for the full code, I'll see if we end up wanting to install and customize Magento for our needs. Your answer was helpful, thanks again.

Comment: Its pleasure assisting you, thanks for vote. Please reach me in case need help.